# Markov proof that a state is either transitive or ergotic - can it be so simple?

Tags: markov-chains

This is the chart associated with a Markov matrix

The equivalence(communication) classes are:

- {1,2,3,4} - transitive
- {5,6,7} - transitive
- {8} - ergotic

My teacher said that "all equivalence classes are either ergotic or transitive". I agree.
However he said, that this was complicated to proof.

I said that suppose there was a class that was both transitive and ergotic. Being ergotic means that once getting in, you can't get out. But if it is also transitive means that you can get out. So, it is only transitive. As a consequence it must be either transitive or ergotic.

My teacher told me that there was a complicated proof, but than what is wrong with mine? Is my proof wrong?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Could you specify your definitions a little more clearly?

Comment: A class is transient if it is possible to leave the state and never return. A class is ergodic if it is not possible to leave the class